# Let $p \in [1, +\infty)$. Then $\mu_m \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$ if and only if $W_p (\mu_m, \mu) \to 0$

Tags: weak-convergence, optimal-transport

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments.

---

Let $p \in [1, +\infty)$, $X=Y$ be compact subsets of $\mathbb R^d$, $\mathcal P (X)$ the set of all Borel probability measures on $X$, and
$$
\mathcal P_p (X) := \left \{\mu \in \mathcal P(X) \,\middle\vert\, \int_X |x|^p \mathrm d \mu < +\infty \right \}.
$$

We define the $p$-th [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Definition) $W_p$ by
$$
W_p (\mu, \nu) := \inf_{\gamma \in \Pi(\mu, \nu)} \left [ \int_{X \times Y} |x-y|^p \mathrm d \gamma (x, y) \right ]^{1/p} \quad \forall \mu, \nu \in \mathcal P_p (X).
$$

Here $\Pi(\mu, \nu)$ is the set of all Borel probability measures on $X\times Y$ whose marginals are $\mu, \nu$ respectively.

> **Theorem:** Let $\mu, \mu_m \in \mathcal P_p(X)$. Then $\mu_m \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$ if and only if $W_p (\mu_m, \mu) \to 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
W^p_1 (\mu, \nu) \le W^p_p (\mu, \nu) \le (\mathrm{diam} X)^p W_1 (\mu, \nu) \quad \forall p \in [1, +\infty).
$$

So it suffices to prove for $p=1$. Let
$$
\mathrm{Lib} (f) := \sup_{x\neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|}.
$$

1. Assume $W_1 (\mu_m, \mu) \to 0$.

By [Kantorovich-Rubinstein](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488387/kantorovich-rubinstein-theorem) theorem, we have
$$
W_1 (\mu_m, \nu) = \sup \left \{\int_X f \mathrm d (\mu_m-\nu)  \,\middle\vert\, f \in L_1 (|\mu_m-\nu|) , \mathrm{Lib} (f) \le 1\right \}.
$$

Let $f$ be bounded Lipschitz-continuous such that $\mathrm{Lib} (f) > 0$. Then $\frac{f}{\mathrm{Lib} (f)}$ is $1$-Lipschitz. Then
$$
\int_X \frac{f}{\mathrm{Lib} (f)} \mathrm d (\mu_m-\nu) \to 0.
$$

So
$$
\int_X f \mathrm d (\mu_m-\nu) \to 0,
$$

The result then follows from [Portmanteau theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434275/the-space-of-bounded-lipschitz-continuous-functions-is-dense-in-that-of-bounded?rq=1).

2. Assume $\mu_m \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} \mu$.

Let $m_k$ be a subsequence such that
$$
\lim_k W_1 (\mu_{m_k}, \mu) = \limsup_m W_1 (\mu_m, \mu).
$$

Fix $a \in X$. Let $g_k$ be a Lipschitz funtion such that $\mathrm{Lib} (g_k) \le 1$ and
$$
W_1 (\mu_{m_k}, \mu) \le \int_X g_k \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu) + \frac{1}{k} = \int_X (g_k - g_k (a)) \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu) + \frac{1}{k} .
$$

It follows from $(\mu_{m_k} - \mu) (X) = 0$ that
$$
\int_X g_k (a) \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu) = 0 \quad \forall k.
$$

Let $g'_k := g_k - g_k (a)$. Then $\mathrm{Lib} (g'_k) \le 1$ and $(g'_k)_k$ is bounded by   $\mathrm{diam} X$. By [Arzelà–Ascoli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458960/two-equivalent-versions-of-arzel%c3%a0-ascoli-theorem) theorem, there is $g$ and a subsequence (re-labelled) such that $g'_k \to g$ in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. Clearly, $\mathrm{Lib} (g) \le 1$. Finally,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_X g'_k \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu) &= \int_X (g'_k-g) \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu) + \int_X g \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu) \\
&= \int_X (g'_k-g) \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu)^+ - \int_X (g'_k-g) \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu)^-  + \int_X g \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu) \\
&\le 2 \|g'_k-g\|_\infty (\mu_{m_k} - \mu)^+ (X) + \int_X g \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu) \\
&\le 4 \|g'_k-g\|_\infty + \int_X g \mathrm d (\mu_{m_k} - \mu).
\end{align}
$$

The result then follows by taking the limit $k \to \infty$.