# Brezis' exercise 6.12: $\forall \varepsilon>0\,\exists C_\varepsilon > 0$ s.t. $\|u\|_\infty \le\varepsilon \|u'\|_\infty + C_\varepsilon \|u\|_{L^1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, compact-operators

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be real Banach spaces with corresponding norms $|\cdot|_X, |\cdot|_Y, |\cdot|_Z$. Assume that $X \subset Y$ with *compact* injection and that $Y \subset Z$ with *continuous* injection.
>
> 1. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $C_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
>    $$
>    |u|_Y \le \varepsilon |u|_X + C_\varepsilon |u|_Z
>    \quad \forall u \in X.
>    $$
> 2. Prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $C_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
>    $$
>    \|u\|_\infty \le \varepsilon \|u'\|_\infty + C_\varepsilon \|u\|_{L^1}
>    \quad \forall u \in C^1([0, 1]).
>    $$

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (2). Could you please have a check on it?

---

Let $X:=C^1([0, 1]), Y :=C([0, 1])$ and $Z:=L^1([0, 1])$. Let $|\cdot|_X$ be the $C^1$-norm, $|\cdot|_Y$ the supremum norm and $|\cdot|_Z$ the $L^1$-norm. Then we have $|u|_Z \le |u|_Y$ and $|u|_X=|u|_Y+|u'|_Y$ for $u \in X$. Then $X \subset Y$ and $Y \subset Z$ with continuous injections.

Let's prove that $X \subset Y$ with compact injection. Let $B_X$ be the closed unit ball of $X$, i.e.,
$$
B_X := \{u \in X : |u|_X \le 1\} = \{u \in X : \|u\|_\infty + \|u'\|_\infty \le 1\}.
$$

For $u \in B_X$, we have
$$
|u(x)-u(y)| \le \|u'\|_\infty |x-y| \le |x-y|
\quad \forall x, y\in [0, 1].
$$

Then $B_X$ is uniformly equi-continuous. Clearly, $B_X$ is uniformly bounded in $Y$. Then $B_X$ has compact closure in $Y$ by [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458960/two-equivalent-versions-of-arzel%c3%a0-ascoli-theorem).

By (1), for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $C_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$
\|u\|_\infty \le \varepsilon (\|u\|_\infty + \|u'\|_\infty) + C_\varepsilon \|u\|_{L^1}
\quad \forall u \in X.
$$

Then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $C_\varepsilon > 0$ such that
$$
\|u\|_\infty \le \frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon} \|u'\|_\infty + \frac{C_\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon} \|u\|_{L^1}
\quad \forall u \in X.
$$

Clearly, $\frac{\varepsilon}{1-\varepsilon}$ can be arbitrarily small. The claim then follows.

Comment: Seems ok to me.