# Convergent sequence together with its limit point is a compact set

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, $C(X)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions on $Y$, and $\mathcal{F} \subset C(X)$. We say that

- $\mathcal{F}$ is *pointwise bounded* if $\forall x \in X$, the set $\{f(x) \mid f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is bounded.
- $\mathcal{F}$ is *uniformly bounded* if the set $\{f(x) \mid f \in \mathcal{F}, x\in X\}$ is bounded.
- $\mathcal F$ is *pointwise equi-continuous* if $\forall x\in X, \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall f\in \mathcal F$, we get $d(x,y) < \delta \implies |f(y)-f(x)| < \varepsilon$.
- $\mathcal F$ is *uniformly equi-continuous* if $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall f\in \mathcal F$, we get $d(x,y)< \delta \implies |f(y)-f(x)| < \varepsilon$.

[**Wikipedia's ver 1:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces) Assume $X$ is compact. A subset $\mathcal F$ of $C(X)$ is *relatively compact* in $\| \cdot\|_\infty$ if and only if $\mathcal F$ is *pointwise* bounded and *pointwise* equi-continuous.

[**Carothers' ver 2:**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025487/understanding-the-proof-of-the-arzela-ascoli-theorem-from-carothers?rq=1) Assume $X$ is a compact. A subset $\mathcal{F}$ of $C(X)$ is *compact* in $\| \cdot\|_\infty$ if and only if  $\mathcal{F}$ is closed, *uniformly* bounded, and *uniformly* equi-continuous.

I proved that above versions of Arzelà–Ascoli theorem are equivalent [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458960/two-equivalent-versions-of-arzel%c3%a0-ascoli-theorem). Now I want to apply them to get below result.

> **Theorem:** Assume $X$ is compact and $(f_n) \subset C (X)$ such that $f_n \to f \in C(X)$. Then $(f_n)$ is uniformly equi-continuous.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**My attempt:** We need below auxiliary result.

> *Lemma:* Assume $x_n, a \in X$ such that $x_n \to a$. Then $S := \{a, x_1, x_2, \ldots\}$ is compact.
>
> *Proof of lemma:* Let $(O_i)_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of $S$. There is $\hat i$ such that $a \in O_{\hat i}$. There is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n \in O_{\hat i}$ for all $n \ge N$. There is $i_n$ such that $x_n \in O_{i_n}$ for all $n \le N$. Then $\{O_i \mid i \in \{\hat i, i_1, \ldots, i_N\}\}$ is a finite subcover.

Now we come back to our *Theorem*. It follows from our *Lemma* that $\{f, f_1, f_2, \ldots\}$ is compact. Then $(f_n)$ is uniformly equi-continuous by *Carothers' ver 2*. This completes the proof.

Comment: Sure but I mean (and this assumes $f_n \to f \in C(X)$ means $\sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$) without the theorem stated by Carother (which seems fair as they didn't prove the implication used in your argument) it really just comes down to 3 simple facts:
(i) given $\varepsilon>0$ we have $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<|f(x)-f(y)|+2\varepsilon$ for all but finitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$, (ii) any continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous, and (iii) any finite family of [uniformly] continuous functions is [uniformly] equicontinuous.

Comment: @MAPelto Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given and set $\varepsilon':=\varepsilon/4$.

(i) Since $\sup_{x \in X} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that
\begin{align}|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|&\leq |f_n(x)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f_n(y)|\\&<|f(x)-f(y)|+2\varepsilon' \quad\quad\quad\quad\text{ whenever } n \geq N.\end{align}
(ii) Since $f \in C(X)$ and $X$ is compact, there is $\delta_0>0$ so that
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<2\varepsilon' \text{ whenever } d(x,y)<\delta_0.$$
Moreover, for each $k \in [N]:=\{k: 1 \leq k <N \}$ there is $\delta_k>0$ so that
$$|f_k(x)-f_k(y)|<\varepsilon \text{ whenever } d(x,y)<\delta_k.$$
(iii) We set $\delta=\min\{\delta_0,\delta_1, \ldots, \delta_{N-1} \}$ to see that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we now have
$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\varepsilon \text{ whenever } d(x,y)<\delta.$$